# Magento 2 code to get Magento 1 product detail via rest api

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, rest-api

I would like to use Magento 1 rest api to get the product details in Magento 2.

Can anybody help me out on magento 2 code for getting the product details from magento 1.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html