# Magento 2 get frontend store url for a path in admin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In admin code, i would like to get the frontend store url for a path. But, always getting admin url for the path.

```
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getStoreId();
$url = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getUrl("sample/index/test");
```

Expected result in http://{magento-url}/sample/index/test/, but always getting http://{magento-url}/{admin-path}/sample/index/test/

Checked the store model, the getUrl function uses Magento\Backend\Model\Url to get the store url.

Can anybody please, let me know the correct way to get the store url from admin page.

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data as ModuleHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Api {

    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(ModuleHelper $helper, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function doSomeAction() {
        //$customUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . "/sample/index/test";
        $customUrl = $this->_helper->getCustomUrl();
        echo $customUrl;
    }

}


namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function getCustomUrl() {
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getStoreId();
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getUrl("sample/index/test");
    }

}
```

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: I am currently using getBaseUrl() . "path". But, i think this is not the correct way. So, wanted a correct way to get the url path.

Comment: I found this app\code\Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\page\header.phtml  ,In this it is using for customer view

Comment: You can check cms page grid action, how they create url for preview

Comment: can you answer me this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132369/magento-2-code-to-get-magento-1-product-detail-via-rest-api

Answer (score 18):

Might be too late for OP, but hopefully this helps anyone else that lands on this page with the same issue.

The reason you are not getting the frontend URL is due to a preference defined in the core code, specifically:

**magento/module-backend/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** *(line 12 in CEv2.1)*

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\UrlInterface" type="Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface" />
```

In order to solve it you have two options

1) Create your own preference for UrlInterface (in your own module), and determine in your code when the backend/frontend URL should be returned.  (strictly speaking, this would be most in-line with Magento code guidelines, but IMO is overkill if you only need it a few times)

2) Call the frontend Url.php (which implements UrlInterface) in the constructor of the file you need to get the URL in.  This will bypass the preference and give you a frontend URL.  Partial code example shown below

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Url */
protected $urlHelper;

public function __construct(
    <<insert your other required files here>>
    \Magento\Framework\Url $urlHelper,
) {
    <<insert parent/other required objects here>>
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
}

public function getFrontendUrl($routePath, $routeParams)
{
    return $this->urlHelper->getUrl($routePath, $routeParams)
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $url = $this->getFrontendUrl(
        'quotes/history/view',
        array(  //any parameters should be passed in array format
            'id' => $mageQuote->getId(), 
            '_nosid' => true  //prevents sessionId from getting added
        )
    );
    // $url = 'https://www.domainname.com/quotes/history/view/id/###/'
}
```

Comment: It took my a while to work out how to specify a particular store to generate it from (important if you have multiple stores). I passed the store_id to the options array as follows:
`$this->urlHelper->getUrl(
'quotes/history/view', [
  '_scope' => $storeId,
  'id' => $mageQuote->getId(),
  '_nosid' => true
]);`

Comment: @RobertEgginton thanks, it worked perfectly for me

Comment: All possible URL parameters can be found here: \Magento\Framework\Url::$_reservedRouteParams

Comment: @RobertEgginton its not working for me in Magento 2.3.2

Answer (score 4):

You can get store url from admin by passing the scope parameters as following

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Url */
protected $urlHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Url $urlHelper
) {
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
}

public function getFrontendUrl()
{
    $storeId = 1;
    $id = 10;
    return $this->urlHelper->getUrl( 'quotes/history/view', [ '_scope' => $storeId, 'id' => $id, '_nosid' => true ]);
}
```

Comment: not working me !

Answer (score 0):

You can write code in  Helper/Data.php to get store url and using data helper call that method in admin page

for example

Helper/Data.php

```
public function getStoreUrl(){
    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getStoreId();
    $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getUrl("sample/index/test");
return $url;

}
```

In admin page 
In block

```
public function __construct(
    \Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data $_dataHelper
) {
    $this->_dataHelper = $_dataHelper;
}
```

get url - `$this->_dataHelper->getStoreUrl();`

In phtml

```
$block->helper('Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data')->getStoreUrl();
```

**For Magento 2.1**

in block or phtml

```
echo $this->getBaseUrl().'sample/test/test';
```

Comment: Sorry, i am still getting the admin url only.... http://{magento-url}/{admin-path}/sample/index/test/

Comment: @santhoshkumar can you show me how you implemented this code?

Comment: Added the sample code in the question

Comment: @santhoshkumar i tested this code its working its giving frontend url

Comment: you tested in your frontend page or backend page? call the url in the admin page. I am using magento 2.1.0.

Comment: Backend page and In 2.1.0 its not working

Comment: Please note that you should not use `$block->helper(CLASS)` in your PHTML templates. PHTML templates are only to be used to output data. Any other logic needs to be placed in the Block class itself, not its template.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `websiteRepositoryInterface` like this:

```
use Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface
```

Now declare it in class constructor and then use it like:

```
$this->websiteRepositoryInterface->getDefault()->getDefaultStore()->getUrl("xyz/test/index")
```

It will give you default website front-end url.