# How to get product's frontend url from backend?

Tags: magento2, product, url, frontend

I am developing a extension of Magento 2. I need to get a product's frontend url from backend. I have tried to use:

```
//$storeManager->->setCurrentStore(2);
$url = $product->setStoreId(2)->getProductUrl();
$url = $product->setStoreId(2)->getUrlInStore();
```

but the `$url` always return a backend url, like `http://<domain>/admin/catalog/product....`. they may work in Magento 1.x but not for 2.x. Is there any way to get frontend url?

Comment: You might face a similar problem as I in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138216/get-frontend-category-url-in-admin-area-with-correct-base-url - this is totally broken in M2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add new constructor dependency to your class forntUrlModel:

```
function __construct(
    ...
     \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $frontUrlModel
) {
    $this->frontUrlModel = $frontUrlModel;
}

private function getProductUrl($product, $storeCode = 'default', $categoryId = null) {
        $routeParams = [ '_nosid' => true, '_query' => ['___store' => $storeCode]];

        $routeParams['id'] = $product->getId();
        $routeParams['s'] = $product->getUrlKey();
        if ($categoryId) {
            $routeParams['category'] = $categoryId;
        }
     return $this->frontUrlModel->getUrl('catalog/category/view', $routeParams);
 }
```

And use DI to inject right dependency

```
<type name="YouClass"> 
    <arguments>
        <argument name="frontUrlModel" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Framework\Url</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: thanks. I see you inject UrlInterface and define dependency in Di.xml.  Why don't you inject `\Magento\Framwork\Url` directly?

Comment: Interface segregation principle, from  S.O.L.I.D

Comment: @KAndy  i had tried this.. but unable to get the product url.. :(  please post the full code here.. I'm trying to make a column in product grid with product frontend link.

Comment: @KAndy what is the YouClass means? we need to make any class here.

Can you please more elaborate it so this answer can help many others like me

Answer (score 7):

I answer my question. 
mtns_cll's answer the question of  [Magento 2 get frontend store url for a path in admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132548/magento-2-get-frontend-store-url-for-a-path-in-admin) works for me.

I post my solution here in case someone need it:

**product frontend**:

inject `\Magento\Framework\Url $url`

```
$url->getUrl('catalog/product/view', ['id' => $entityId, '_nosid' => true, '_query' => ['___store' => $storeCode]]);
```

**product backend**

inject `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url` or use url interface inherited from parent class.

```
$url->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['id' => $entityId, 'store' => $targetStoreId]);
```

**category frontend**

inject `\Magento\Framework\Url $url

```
$url->getUrl('catalog/category/view', ['id' => $entityId, '_nosid' => true, '_query' => ['___store' => $storeCode]]);
```

**category backend**

inject `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url` or use url interface inherited from parent class.

```
$url->getUrl('catalog/category/edit', ['id' => $entityId, 'store' => $targetStoreId]);
```

**cms page frontend**

inject `Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder $rul`

```
$url->getUrl($this->_pageModel->getIdentifier(), $targetStoreId, $storeCode );
```

**cms page backend**

inject `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url` or use url interface inherited from parent class.

```
$url->getUrl(PageActions::CMS_URL_PATH_EDIT, ['page_id' => $pageId]);
```

**cms block backend**

inject `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url` or use url interface inherited from parent class.

```
$url->getUrl(BlockActions::URL_PATH_EDIT, ['block_id' => $blockId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Magento/Store/Model/StoreManager`. Inject it into a constructor via `Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface`, more or less like this:

```
    public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
   .....
) {
   ...
$this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
}
$requestedStoreObject = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
$urlToRequestedStore = $requestedStoreObject->getUrl();
```

You should notice that function `getStore()` as an argument can take not only integer, but also string or object:

```
/**
 * Retrieve application store object
 *
 * @param null|string|bool|int|\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $storeId
 * @return \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface
 */
public function getStore($storeId = null);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. it returns backend url, like http://<domain>/admin/....