# how to get ProductUrl at backend , in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-urls

I wan to get productUrl at backend side.

I am trying it by productrepository. I am getting right url at custom controller.

But when I'm trying it in import module's start controller I'm getting admin extra.

Like:

expected: www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/9450/s/testProduct

Actualresult: www.example.com/**adminBoard**/catalog/product/view/id/9450/s/testProduct

I have already refer [How to get product's frontend url from backend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143448/how-to-get-products-frontend-url-from-backend/143597)

but not reached at solution.

Comment: Can you please upload your file code?

Comment: I have product id and product obj at backend  how can i get frontend product url? @RohanHapani 

my code cannot help you

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if not working. (use store code if require)

Comment: it's working in this controller but not working in \Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Start

Comment: okay. Let me check.

Comment: I checked in my Magento. It's working successfully. Is there any system.log or exception.log ?

Comment: Compare your code and my answer's code. Maybe, you'll get idea.

Comment: Please accept and upvote answer, if answer was helpful for you. So, it will helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Url;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        Url $url,
        ....
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //your code logic
        $productId = 'your product id';
        $storeCode = 'your store code';
        echo $this->_url->getUrl('catalog/product/view', ['id' => $productId, '_nosid' => true, '_query' => ['___store' => $storeCode]]);
    }

}
```